The results of the code are different from the Ubuntu terminal using vscode's remote ssh and the actual Ubuntu terminal
The code I use is python code written in vscode.
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

def on_press(key):
    try:
        print('key is pressed: {0}'.format(key.char))
    except AttributeError:
        print('anomaly key is pressed: {0}'.format(key))

def on_release(key):
    print('key is released: {0}'.format(key))
    if key == Key.esc:
        return False

with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()

python version is 3.8.10 and pynput version is latest update version
The ssh remote bash terminal does not respond to keyboard input, but If i run it directly using a Ubuntu terminal connected via VNC, it will output normally.
Even the python code executed in ssh does not respond to input from the ssh terminal, but responds to input from the actual Ubuntu terminal. I don't know why this happens
I would like to have vscode's ssh terminal output the results normally. help me please
directly using a Ubuntu terminal
ssh remote bash terminal
this is my .bashrc all config
alias sb="source ~/.bashrc; echo \"bashrc is reloaded.\""
alias domain="export ROS_DOMAIN_ID=13"
alias galactic="source /opt/ros/galactic/setup.bash; echo>
alias my_study="source /home/pi/ros2_study/install/local_>
source /opt/ros/galactic/setup.bash
echo "Ros2 galactic is activated."
export ROS_PATH=/opt/ros/galactic/bin
export DISPLAY=:0

